# Can't stop recursion, while iterating a template type list

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, typelist, infinite-recursion

So I have a template type list like this :

```
template <typename... Types>
struct type_list
{
};
```

I've made an accessor function like this :

```
template<class TypeList, size_t ElementIndex>
struct at;

template <template<typename...> class TypeList, typename Head, typename... OtherTypes, size_t ElementIndex>
struct at<  TypeList<Head, OtherTypes...>,  ElementIndex>
{
    static_assert(ElementIndex < (size_v<   TypeList<Head, OtherTypes...>   >), "at_t : ElementIndex is bigger than list size");

    using type = if_else_t < ElementIndex == 0, Head, typename at<  TypeList<OtherTypes...>, ElementIndex - 1   >::type >;
};

template <template<typename...> class TypeList, typename Last, size_t ElementIndex>
struct at<  TypeList<Last>, ElementIndex>
{
    static_assert(ElementIndex < (size_v<   TypeList<Last>  >), "at_t : ElementIndex is bigger than list size");

    using type = Last;
};

template<class TypeList, size_t ElementIndex>
using at_t = typename at<TypeList, ElementIndex>::type;
```

the `if_else_t<>` has the following implementation :

```
template<bool Condition, typename True, typename False>
struct if_else
{
    using type = True;
};

template<typename True, typename False>
struct if_else<false, True, False>
{
    using type = False;
};
```

Now if I test the function with :

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<   bool, at_t< type_list<int, float, bool, char>, 2    >   >, "at_t : Bad result");
```

I trigger the static_assert that check if the ElementIndex is bigger than the list size.
From the compiler's output I can clearly see that the `at<>` never stop the recursion, until ElementIndex hits his numerical limit (the case where ElementIndex = 0 - 1) and the static_assert is triggered.

What am I doing wrong ?

Ideal answer should also include a better, more elegant, implementation of `at<>` :)

Please note that I'm using MSVC and C++17.

Comment: `std::tuple_element<Index, Tuple>`?

Comment: Good question ! I'm doing this in the scope of a personal project and so I would like to understand how things works behind the scene. I'm also pretty new to TMP and doing so allow me to train myself to TMP basic idioms and algorithms :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you do this:

```cpp
if_else_t < ElementIndex == 0, Head, typename at<  TypeList<OtherTypes...>, ElementIndex - 1   >::type >;
```

Even if `ElementIndex` is `0`, the other two types still have to be evaluated to be passed to `if_else_t` (thus triggering the `static_assert`).

You fix it by using specialisation instead:

```cpp
template<class TypeList, size_t ElementIndex>
struct at;

template <template<typename...> class TypeList, typename Head, typename... OtherTypes>
struct at<  TypeList<Head, OtherTypes...>,  0>
{
    using type = Head;
};

template <template<typename...> class TypeList, typename Head, typename... OtherTypes, size_t ElementIndex>
struct at<  TypeList<Head, OtherTypes...>,  ElementIndex>
{
    static_assert(ElementIndex < (size_v<   TypeList<Head, OtherTypes...>   >), "at_t : ElementIndex is bigger than list size");

    using type = typename at<  TypeList<OtherTypes...>, ElementIndex - 1   >::type;
};

template <template<typename...> class TypeList, size_t ElementIndex>
struct at<  TypeList<>,  ElementIndex>
{
    static_assert(ElementIndex != ElementIndex, "at_t : ElementIndex is bigger than list size");
};
```

Or you can use the standard [`tuple_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element)

```cpp
template<class TypeList, size_t ElementIndex>
struct at;

template <template<typename...> class TypeList, typename... Types, size_t ElementIndex>
struct at<  TypeList<Types...>,  ElementIndex>
{
    static_assert(ElementIndex < (sizeof...(Types)), "at_t : ElementIndex is bigger than list size");

    using type = std::tuple_element_t<ElementIndex, std::tuple<Types...>>;
};
```

---

As a side note, `if_else_t` is just [`std::conditional_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional)

Comment: `static_assert(ElementIndex != ElementIndex);` can be treated as `static_assert(false)` (even if dependent). `template <size_t> struct always_false : std::false_type{};` and `static_assert(always_false<ElementIndex>)` would be good (as `always_false` might be specialized to have valid template).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Oops I totally missed `std::conditional`. As specified in a comment above I don't use tuple and tuple_element, to better understand how things works behind the scene. So yeah, with specialization it works great :) I just don't understand how the specialization `struct at<  TypeList<Head, OtherTypes...>,  0>` actually works with lists with only one element. I mean this specialization should expect lists with at least 2 elements (Head and **1** OtherTypes). Could you please elaborate, eventually editing your answer ?

Comment: @AntonioCantarella `OtherTypes...` is a parameter pack that can hold any number of types, including zero types.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
using type = if_else_t<ElementIndex == 0,
                       Head,
                       typename at<TypeList<OtherTypes...>, ElementIndex - 1>::type>;
```

`typename at<  TypeList<OtherTypes...>, ElementIndex - 1   >::type` Has to be evaluated. and so instantiation of `at<TypeList<OtherTypes...>, ElementIndex - 1>`

You might delay(and so remove) instantiation with:

```
using type = typename if_else_t<ElementIndex == 0,
                                std::type_identity<Head>, // C++20, but trivial rewrite
                                at<TypeList<OtherTypes...>, ElementIndex - 1>>::type;
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e3479e882062fd0)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. So I wrote `template< typename T >struct type_identity{ using type = T; };` and its alias `type_identity_t`. I followed your answer, but I still get the same problem.

Comment: @AntonioCantarella: Demo link added.